# How do I create a jQuery preloader with a percentage counter?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have written this code I learnt from a beginners jQuery book, which works great as a preloader for the page, but how do i create a percentage (%) counter for it? - Based upon how much body content is loaded? At the moment I just have an animated GIF - but I'd like something a little more advanced! :)

```
// Lets preload!
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).remove(); });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#preloader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #009933 url(uploads/images/ajax-loader2.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What you are doing here is not a preloader. You are just showing an image until the content is loaded ...

Comment: @Jan - Yes you are right, I am trying to show a progress counter/page until the content is loaded in effect giving the same effect as a preloader. It doesn't need to 'technically'be a preloader, just give the illusion so that the main page loads in the order it needs to in the background, unseen by the user, then shows a tidy loaded page when it's ready.

Answer (score 1):

this [jQuery plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/progress-bar-plugin/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I used  [this plug-in](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/) for my website... maybe it's ok for you as well..