# I want to make a nice looking percentage preloader for my website but do i have to use flash?

Tags: html, css, flash, preloader

So i want to make a percentage preloader for my website but wonder if i have to make it in flash or if there is a better or easier way to do it? Ive been making gif preloaders before with photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS3 in this Case! Flash is out of date...

Have a look an CSS3 transition and transform!

[Try it!](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/)

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have to use Flash. In fact, flash is hardly ever a good choice for anything these days.

you can do it with CSS animations

here is a link to a great tutorial that shows you how

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/05/page-preloading-effect/

You can also do it with jQuery, there are lots of pre made plug ins out there for you to use. Take a look at these -

http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-preloader-image/

Answer (score 0):

No, you haven't. There are many other technologies that can do that.

Simple percentage preloader search on stackoverflow.com gives the following solutions:

- [Q: JavaScript preloader/progress/percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354640/javascript-preloader-progress-percentage)
- [Q: jQuery preloader with a percentage counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240993/how-do-i-create-a-jquery-preloader-with-a-percentage-counter)
- [Q: CSS3 preloader with percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844464/creating-preloader-with-percentage-in-css3)